# Finding the rank of a 4 by 5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Problem:

Find the rank of the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
Answer:
\begin{align*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 5 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & -4 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & -6 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -8 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -\frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{8} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{8} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
 2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -2 & 5 & \dfrac{41}{8} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{3}{8} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{8} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
If I were to continue the process it seems clear to me that would put the
matrix in reduced row echelon form and have four independent vectors. Hence
the rank of this matrix is $4$.

However, the book gets $3$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have an arithmetic error in the first step.  To get a 0 in the first column, fourth row, subtract twice the first row from the fourth row.  In the second row, you should have 7- 2(3)= 1, not -1.

Comment: After the first operation $a_{42} $should be $1$ instead of$ -1$

Comment: Also the first, a_{32} should be 4 instead of 5.

Comment: To keep one's rank is hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is wrong because there was a  mistake in putting the matrix in reduced row echelon form. Here is a correct solution.

Using an online calculator, I find that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & -2 & 5 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
2 & 7 & -3 & 6 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 22 & -21 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Hence the rank of the matrix is $3$.